# How in MVC4 adding constraint to DB column Without running migration tool

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have completed the application but now i need to do some validation and constrain ...How in MVC4 adding constraint to DB column Without running migration tool..

now model looks like

```
    public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
```

but i want to add

```
//[Required]
    public string AlbumTitle { get; set; }
```

without any major modification or Without running migration tool

Comment: You can directly make that field in DB Not Null with some default constraint using alter table and add the [Required] Attribute as per your post manually.

Comment: Tks, but i get below error now at `db.SaveChanges();` `Cannot insert the value NULL into column .....`

Comment: Its behaving as expected as we made the column not null, so as per my previous comment add [Required] attribute and validate the model before calling db.SaveChanges.

Comment: tks all ... i have one it